# Using octave headless

Tags: terminal, octave, headless

Is there a possibility to use Octave headless.

Something like this

`octave < "5+4" >result.txt`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using

```
octave --silent --eval 5+4 > result.txt
```

you'll get

```
ans =  9
```

in `result.txt`. See `octave --help` for details about command-line arguments.

Yet, there is this infamous `ans =` that might be remove using `sed`, e.g.

```
octave --silent --eval 'x=5+4; y=x+1; disp(y)' | sed -e 's/ans = //' >> result.txt
```

which add the appropriate result (`10`) in `result.txt`.

It should not be too hard to wrap this into a `bash` script.

Answer (score 5):

Well there is always the option of writing a script file which saves the results of your computations to a text file. Then when invoking octave you just do:

```
octave scriptname.m
```

for example:
**testfile.m**

```
Return = 5+4;
save('results.txt','Return')
```

Then from the command line:

```
octave -q testfile.m
```

and you should get the results you want in a file called *results.txt* and it will immediately terminate after. Is there some reason why this option wont work?